# How to append binary file with a binary file in C++

Tags: c++, iostream, binaryfiles

I have two binary files and I would like to append one with the other.
How can I do it?

```
std::ofstream outFile;
outFile.open( "file.bin", ? );
```

what should be the nest line?

Comment: Read everything from file 2 and write it to file 1.

Comment: Probably you should read one file and write the other after seeking to end. Why don't show show that you have really tried?

Comment: Open the files (in binary mode), seek to the end of the first (destination) file, read from second (source) file while writing to first file. And yes, there are some [open mode flags](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode) that can help you with that.

Comment: I wanted to know is there is any shorter way to append it.

Answer (score 3):

There's a one liner for this:

```
std::ofstream outFile("file.out", std::ios::ate );
std::ifstream inFile( "file.in" );

std::copy( 
    (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(inFile)),  // (*)
     std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(),
     std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(outFile)
);
```

<sub>(*) Extra pair of parentheses to prevent parsing this as function declaration.</sub>

For better performance you could read the file in chunks, using `ifstream::read` and write them with `ofstream::write`.

Comment: Nice. One small remark: shouldn't the outFile be opened with `ios::app` ?

Comment: @MartinJ. Thanks, wrong one. `ate`, `app`, it doesn't really matter as we're not seeking between writes.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I've been under impression that it's not needed when using `streambuf` iterators. Will double check.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Seems to be fine.

Comment: Or you can just do `outFile << inFile.rdbuf()`.

Comment: @0x499602D2 I keep forgetting about that one!

Answer (score 0):

This is not the most optimal, but you can try something like:

```
std::ofstream outFile( "file.bin", ios_base::app | ios_base::out );

std::ifstream inFile(source_file_name, ios_base::binary | ios_base::in);
source >> noskipws;
char c;
while (inFile >> c) {
    outFile << c;
}
```

You can make probably make it more efficient by using a bigger buffer.